# Elasticsearch Similar Text Query

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, elasticsearch-query

Given the following documents in an index (lets call it **addresses**):

```
{
    ADDRESS: {
        ID: 1,
        LINE1: "steet 1",
        CITY: "kuala lumpur",
        COUNTRY: "MALAYSIA",
        ...
    } 
}
{
    ADDRESS: {
        ID: 2,
        LINE1: "steet 1",
        CITY: "kualalumpur city",
        COUNTRY: "MALAYSIA",
        ...
    }
}
{
    ADDRESS: {
        ID: 3,
        LINE1: "steet 1",
        CITY: "kualalumpur",        
        COUNTRY: "MALAYSIA",
        ...
    }
}
{
    ADDRESS: {
        ID: 4,
        LINE1: "steet 1",
        CITY: "kuala lumpur city",      
        COUNTRY: "MALAYSIA",
        ...
    }
}
```

At this point, I found the query to grab "kualalumpur", "kuala lumpur", "kualalumpur city" with the search text "kualalumpur".
But "kuala lumpur city" is missing from the result despite near similarity with "kualalumpur city".

Here is my query so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
          {"match": {"ADDRESS.STREET": {"query": "street 1", "fuzziness": 1, "operator": "AND"}}},
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {"match": {"ADDRESS.CITY": {"query": "kualalumpur", "fuzziness": 1, "operator": "OR"}}},
                {"match": {"ADDRESS.CITY.keyword": {"query": "kualalumpur", "fuzziness": 1, "operator": "OR"}}}
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"term": {"ADDRESS.COUNTRY.keyword": "MALAYSIA"}}
          ]
        }
      },
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Given the condition, is it possible at all for Elasticsearch to return all four documents with search text "kualalumpur"?

Comment: it would be great if you can let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hey! Indeed it does! Thanks, one follow up question, what is the benefit of choosing edge n-gram in this case instead of n-gram?

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Comment: No issues, my pleasure

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [edge-n gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) on the `country` field to get the all four docs, **tried it in my local and adding below working example.**

Create custom analyzer and apply it on your field

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "ngram_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                        ],
                        "tokenizer": "edgeNGramTokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "edgeNGramTokenizer": {
                        "token_chars": [
                            "letter",
                            "digit"
                        ],
                        "min_gram": "1",
                        "type": "edgeNGram",
                        "max_gram": "40"
                    }
                }
            },
            "max_ngram_diff": "50"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "country": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer" : "ngram_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index your all four sample docs, like below**

```
{
  "country" : "kuala lumpur"
}
```

**search query with term `kualalumpur` matches all four docs**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "country" : "kualalumpur"
        }
    }
}

 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "fuzzy",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 5.0003963,
        "_source": {
          "country": "kualalumpur"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fuzzy",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 4.4082437,
        "_source": {
          "country": "kualalumpur city"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fuzzy",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5621849,
        "_source": {
          "country": "kuala lumpur"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fuzzy",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.4956103,
        "_source": {
          "country": "kuala lumpur city"
        }
      }
    ]
```